# Use SequenceEqual and reflection

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I'm trying to compare some selected items in a grid with a list stored in the session for find which one is selected.
For simplify the comparison I want to use link, reflection and SequenceEqual().

So I try like this :

```
(from item in SessionList
where item.GetType().GetProperties().SequenceEqual(gridProduct.GetType().GetProperties())
select item).Single();
```

But it doesn't work, I have many items selected by the link query whereas only one should be selected.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: `GetProperties` does not do what you think it does (read the docs). Reflection is a very bad way to solve this problem; do it in a type safe manner instead. There is not enough information in the question to tell you what that might be.

Comment: Ok, I was afraid by this answer, so I will use a "manual" method. Thanks for your help